# Implement sliding window with three input variables, list, window size and forward move size using python?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, sliding-window

I have a list like this,

```
  l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

Now I want to apply a sliding window of size five (n1), but it will move forward by three steps(n2).

The desired output I am looking for if n1=5 and n2=3 is,

```
[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8],[7,8,9,10,11],[10,11,12,13,14],[13,14,15,16,17],[16,17,18,19,20]
```

I could use following code,

```
[ thelist[x:x+size] for x in range( len(thelist) - size + 1 ) ]  # but this returns only one 
forward move.
```

How to move it more than 1 ?

I can use for loop, but execution time will be huge.

How to implement it with less execution time ?

Comment: Use [`range()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)'s `step` argument

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`[thelist[x: x + 5] for x in range(0,len(thelist),3)  if x + 5 <= len(thelist)]`

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
```

Comment: I would prefer `[thelist[x:x + size] for x in range(0, len(thelist) - size + 1, step)]` because otherwise the stop argument of `range` is redundant.